# TextBlock text aligned right, but positioned from the left in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

In WPF XAML, if I have a `<TextBlock />` manually positioned 100 pixels to the left, inside a `<Canvas />`, is it possible that the text, for example 'Hello World', starts drawing at the 100 pixel left mark, **but** then moves leftwards, the more text is added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextBlock` has a [`TextAlignment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textalignment(v=vs.110).aspx) property that you would have thought would do what you want.

However, for a `Canvas` this doesn't work. What you need to do is calculate the length of the text and move the left point of the text block accordingly:

```
double offset = 0.0;
double difference = (element.Width) - element.ActualWidth;
switch (element.TextAlignment)
{
    case TextAlignment.Center:
        offset = 0.5 * difference;
        break;
    case TextAlignment.Right:
        offset = difference;
        break;
}
element.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, component.LeftProperty + offset);
```

This should move the TextBlock to the right place.

Comment: Inside a canvas, setting TextAlignment to any value results in the content drawing from the left. Outside of a Canvas (i.e. `Grid`) it only solves half the problem as I want to set the TextBlocks *end* position to be 100 pixels from the left regardless of length.

Comment: @maxp - yes, you're right, my mistake. I'd forgotten that despite having to solve the same problem myself some time ago. I've updated the answer.